# What is the difference between "Bayesian Gaussian Mixture Model" and "Dirichlet Process Gaussian mixtures model" in the Sklearn Python library?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian

This is the link of Byesian Gaussian Mixure model. 
[BayesianGaussianMixture](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.BayesianGaussianMixture.html)

Is it by default parameters a "Dirichlet Process Gaussian mixtures" model ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is, by default. From the documentation for v1.0.2:

> This class implements two types of prior for the weights distribution:
> a finite mixture model with Dirichlet distribution and an infinite
> mixture model with the Dirichlet Process

This is set in the `weight_concentration_prior_type` parameter and the Dirichlet Process is the default.